# How to remove audio file from SDCard by getting it's position

Tags: android, android-listview, audio-recording, listviewitem

I have a custom list-view with check-boxes which get's all audio file name from SD Card folder and when i click any of this it play's audio. Everything is working fine. Now i have a image-view when i click on it, it show's 2 option with spinner

1) Delete
2) Edit

Now i want like this, when user select any check-box from list-view and then delete from this spinner, i want to completely remove this audio from SD Card as well as from List-view. So basically i want to get position of list-view that which item is clicked by user and want to delete it...

So please guide me how can i achieve this. Below is my code.

```
final Spinner spinnerDelete = new Spinner(Assignment.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(spinnerDelete);

            adapterSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    Assignment.this, R.array.delete_menu,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterSpinner
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerDelete.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Data");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to Delete Record!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    if (spinnerDelete
                                            .getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {

                                        Code.i = true;
                                        int len = mListView.getCount();
                                        SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView
                                                .getCheckedItemPositions();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                                            if (checked.get(i)) {
                                                 File file = new File(MEDIAPATH);
                                                 boolean deleted = file.delete();                                                                                                                                   }
```

where media path contains

```
private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AudioRecorder/");
```

I have tried with below link but not getting solution as i want

[How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

[Delete File in SD Card android with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880187/delete-file-in-sd-card-android-with-string)

[Delete file on sd card from a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545477/delete-file-on-sd-card-from-a-listview)

[Delete file on sd card from a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545477/delete-file-on-sd-card-from-a-listview)

[how to delete a particular file from the paticular folder in sdcard when click on check boxes in list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006127/how-to-delete-a-particular-file-from-the-paticular-folder-in-sdcard-when-click-o)

[How can I make a file to disappear once if it is deleted in android SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982647/how-can-i-make-a-file-to-disappear-once-if-it-is-deleted-in-android-sd-card)

Comment: what is the problem you are facing actually. you don't know how to delete file or you don't know how to get file name and path to delete?

Comment: I don't know how to get checked position, means after checking check-box how to delete that particular file.

Comment: At a time you can delete multiple file or only one file at a time.

Comment: only one file at a time.

Comment: If multiple checkboxes are selected in different row and the user delete then what will happen.

Comment: I have given a similar example. Can you check once ?

Comment: Updated I think now it will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed below piece of code and now it's working fine, but thank you all.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (checked.get(i)) {
          String delete = myList.get(i);
          File f = new File(MEDIA_PATH + "/"+ delete);
          if (f != null && f.exists()) {
          f.delete();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar example I am posting hope it can help you. Whatever you are doing on check box same I am doing on delete button. If you want to do it with check box then you must maintain states of all checkboxes or atleast state of last selected checkbox. This is a custom adapter and I have override getView method. Look how I am display toast on button click in listview then you will understand. If still you are facing any problem then you can ask.

```
package com.example.list_view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class array_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context = null;
    ArrayList<String> file_list = null;
    public array_adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.file_list = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row_view = convertView;

        if (row_view == null) {
            row_view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_layout, null);
            TextView text_view = (TextView) row_view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Button button = (Button) row_view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // POSITION YOU HAVE SO YOU CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WANT.
                    String file_name = file_list.get(position);
                    String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AudioRecorder/" + file_name);
                    File file = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
                    file.delete();
                    file_list.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                    // ATTACT FILE WITH CORRECT FILE PATH AND DELETE.
                    Toast.makeText(context, file_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            text_view.setText(file_list.get(position));
        }
        return row_view;
    }
}
```

If you are still facing any problem then you can ask.

Comment: How can i remove file from sdcard with this code. because i am not getting checked position properly.

Comment: This is not exactly what i was looking for, i have bit modified your code, but definitely i am gonna upvote this. Thanks you for your all help. Really and highly appreciate your work.

Comment: Ya thats why I was asking the exact thing you want to do with check box. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically your are not going to delete audio or any file. As you have mention in your question that you have `Index or Position` for each row in list view.

So, Simple is that you have to delete  that path as well as that file also.

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Example : Path `/sdcard/My_App/sample_audio.mp3`

If you have problem with checked item position then go through [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Comment: But with this piece of code i am not able to delete file neither from sdcard or from list-view.

Answer (score 0):

In your "delete" handler you should do the following :

- Get the positions of selected items, as you already do :

  `SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();`
- For each "checked" position :

  1. Construct related file path and remove that file
  2. Remove corresponding data at given position from the adapter
- After adapter data array/list has been updated and size is reduced 
  call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to update mListView